# Forcing Bash to use Perl RegEx Engine

Tags: bash, regular-expression, perl

As you may already know, a lot of the features modern RegEx engines support (back referencing, lookaround assertions, etc.) are not supported by Bash RegEx engine. Following is a simple Bash script I have just created to try to explain what my end goal is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure exactly two arguments are passed.
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage: match [string] [pattern]"
    return
fi

variable=${1}
pattern=${2}

if [[ ${variable} =~ ${pattern} ]]
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

So for instance, something like the following command will return false:

```
. match.sh "catfish" "(?=catfish)fish"
```

whereas the exact same expression will find a match when used in a Perl or a JavaScript regex tester.

Backreferences (e.g. (expr1)(expr2)[ ]\1\2) won't match as well.

I have simply come to the conclusion that my problem will only be solved when forcing bash to use a Perl-compatible RegEx engine.
Is this doable? If so, how would I go about performing the procedure?

Comment: Why don't you just use perl instead of bash for scripting? And why is this question tagged javascript?

Comment: Because using Bash is a must in my situation. And I have accidentally tagged JavaScript. I removed it :)

Comment: Why don't you use `grep` with `-P` or using `sed`?

Comment: But you never explain the situation/problem that made you come to the conclusion that you must have the shell do something it simply can't do. There make be a better way.

Comment: I find that backreferences *do* work in bash 4.3.x (Ubuntu 14.04), but not in bash 3.2x (OS X).  Here is my test command: `re="([a-z])[0-9]\1"; [[ a1a =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bash doesn't support a method for you to do this at this time. You're left with the following options:

1. Use Perl
2. Use `grep [-P|--perl-regexp]`
3. Use Bash functionality to code it

I think I would go with #2 and try and use `grep` to get what I want functionally. For back referencing you can do the following with `grep`:

```
$ echo 'BEGIN `helloworld` END' | grep -oP '(?<=BEGIN `).*(?=` END)'
helloworld
```

---

```
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

---

```
(?=pattern)
    is a positive look-ahead assertion
(?!pattern)
    is a negative look-ahead assertion
(?<=pattern)
    is a positive look-behind assertion
(?<!pattern)
    is a negative look-behind assertion
```

#### References

- [How To Use Backreference in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818747/how-to-use-backreference-in-bash)

Comment: I honestly didn't know grep had a `[-P|--perl-regexp]` token. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @FadiHannaAL-Kass - you're welcome. Thanks for the question.

Comment: For posterity, only GNU grep includes the `-P` option, and it's not universal. FreeBSD's grep is based on GNU, but the documentation states "This option is not supported in FreeBSD". In OSX, grep is also based on GNU, but the `-P` option isn't even mentioned in the man page. And on other unix systems whose grep is not GNU, you're unlikely to see `-P` anywhere at all. If there's the remote possibility you that portability may be useful to you in the future, I recommend avoiding OS-specific options like this.

Comment: `pcregrep` is also an option, if available.

Comment: It should be noted that zsh does exactly what the OP requested, as long as the `REMATCH_PCRE` option is set.

Comment: Here is a simple function based on the second option in this answer that returns 0 if a match is true using grep along with perl regular expression syntax, anchored.  
`function ismatch_perl_re() { echo "${1}" | grep -qoP "^${2}$";}`

Answer (score 2):

One could use `pcregrep`. It comes with the package `pcre` in CentOS and `pcregrep` in Ubuntu.

`grep -P` could have this issue depending on the OS / version:

```
-P, --perl-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.  This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```